# How can I automatically update a TextFieldFormat in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, overriding

Everytime  I change the `text` value of a dynamic textfield I have to immediately also assign a value to the `TextFormat`, or else the text doesn't display anything at all.  It's fine, but annoying and easy to forget.  So my first question is simply if there is something I'm doing wrong with my TextField that the field requires an immediate call to its TextFormat setter (even if it's already been previously set).  If I'm doing everything correctly then my second question is regarding my simple custom class I've made to bypass the repetitive functions.  My method was to override the `text` setter function so that every time I assign a new text value, it also assigns the textFormat value again.  I've only ever overridden maybe 1 or 2 other functions before, so I think that is probably where I'm going wrong.

```
public class DynamicDisplayText extends TextField 
{
    private var textFilter:GradientGlowFilter = new GradientGlowFilter(4,90,[0xFE23C1, 0xFC9625, 0xFCFFBF], [0, .5, 1], [0, 125, 250],15,15,2,2,"outer",true);
    private var _format:TextFormat;

    public function DynamicDisplayText(format:TextFormat, filtersArray:Array, txt:String):void 
    {
        super();
        text = txt;
        _format = format;
        selectable = false;
        mouseEnabled = false;
        embedFonts = true;
        setTextFormat(_format);
        autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        filters = filtersArray
    }   

    override public function get text():String { return super.text }
    override public function set text(text:String):void {
        super.text = text 
        super.setTextFormat(_format);   // This seems to be the root of the problem

    }

}
```

If I remove the `super.setTextFormat(_format);` and call the `setTextFormat` function from the Main doc. class, then all works fine.  I get error #2007 parameter value must be non null.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: did you tried [**defaultTextFormat**](http://help.adobe.com/pl_PL/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat)?

Comment: and about e#2007 this only tells me that your `_format` is `null` - you are setting text before setting format. If you change line `private var _format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();` it should work.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I have not! Sounds promising. Thanks for the tip. I'll try that at lunch and report back if I can.

Comment: Thanks That did it.  Glad it was something so simple.

Comment: You do set the text before assigning _format in your constructor :) Just assign the _format in the first line - maybe even before the super() - not sure if the text will be set to "" there. I would get rid of that new TextFormat(), it is just adding up to the CPU / GC load for no reason

Comment: @Philarmon yes, but in my case just setting the text then format only worked *until* I changed the text again. I think when you change the text the format goes back to the default. So it seems anyway. Maybe that's only the case with embedded fonts? I don't know. At any rate I set defaultTextFormat in all my text fields and was able to get rid of all my additional setTextFormat calls throughout my code. So it seems Pawel is correct?

Comment: @Philarmon oh I see you are referring to Pawel's second comment, and yes I realized he was not making a valid point there. He missed that I set the format in the constructor.